# MongoDB query and aggregation for BSON date type

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am working on a project which needs to expire unaccepted orders after a set amount of time.
Here is the sample structure of an order:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  time: int
  history: {
    created_at: Date,
    accepted_at: ['Null', 'Date'],
    completed_at: ['Null', 'Date']
  }
}
```

If `accepted_at` field is still null after  some hours from `created_at`, the order will be considered as expired.

If order is accepted and `completed_at` is still null after `time` hours from `created_at` the order will be failed.

I want to get failed orders from document. Something like this:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "history.accepted_at": { $exists: true },
      "history.created_at" : {
         $exists: true,
         $lte: new Date((new Date()).getTime() - $time *3600 * 1000)
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: so, created_at will always be less than now ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I think find method is not enough. Maybe aggregate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to store values of timestamps for all, that is most universal solution & also easy to manipulate for queries of such kind

So your schema be like

```
{
    time:{
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    history:{
        created_at:{
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        accepted_at:{
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        completed_at:{
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        }
    }
}
```

And then write your query like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "end_deadline": {
        $add: [
          "$history.created_at",
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$time",
              3600000
            ]
          }
        ]
      },

    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "history.accepted_at": {
        $exists: true
      },
      "history.completed_at": null,
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          ISODate("2020-01-23T00:00:00.441Z"),
          "$end_deadline"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Sample Data

```
[
  {
    "time": 12,
    "start_from": 1579910400441,
    "history": {
      "created_at": 1579737600441,
      "accepted_at": 1579741200441
    }
  },
  {
    "time": 24,
    "start_from": 1579932000441,
    "history": {
      "created_at": 1579737600441,
      "accepted_at": 1579739400441,
      "completed_at": 1579935600441
    }
  },
  {
    "time": 24,
    "start_from": 1578700800441,
    "history": {
      "created_at": 1578528000441,
      "accepted_at": 1578614400441
    }
  }
]
```

Sample response

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "end_deadline": 1.579780800441e+12,
    "history": {
      "accepted_at": 1.579741200441e+12,
      "created_at": 1.579737600441e+12
    },
    "start_from": 1.579910400441e+12,
    "time": 12
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "end_deadline": 1.578614400441e+12,
    "history": {
      "accepted_at": 1.578614400441e+12,
      "created_at": 1.578528000441e+12
    },
    "start_from": 1.578700800441e+12,
    "time": 24
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like to deal with timezone problems. Is timestamp good for working with timezone changes?

Comment: Also, as far as I know, default value is not supported in MongoDB. In what MongoDB framework is your schema used?

Comment: Yes, Indeed using timestamp would be perfect if you want to deal with timezones as timestamp stays constant at a particular moment throughout the universe so you just have to convert it to the actual time when you need to access it (i.e. client side)

Comment: I use mongoose orm, which in my opinion is the best to use when working with mongodb, as traditionally mongodb does not have anything like schema, the default thing is from mongoose

Comment: @Sarfaaz I used your query and have some problem. Please check this url: https://mongoplayground.net/p/eR3t942RLsd
Comparing deadline and current date is not working correctly.

Comment: I have fixed an issue in the query, but the query is written considering the date values are stored as timestamps(Number) and not date, so I don't think it will work with date type values

Comment: I have added sample data & response for your reference

Comment: I don't know what timestamps you used. But it should return only one document for given query. But it's returning two.

Comment: I think using new Date is not correct. I changed it into ISODate("2020-01-23T00:00:00.441Z"), and it's finally working correctly. Please reflect this in your answer and I'll accept it. The url I have provided earlier includes correct answer in datetime format.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I used a javascript function new date() which was not correct, You can write your own code to get current dateTime & put the value there. I have updated my answer to reflect same

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct answer for BSON Date type.

**Sample Data**

```
[
  {
    "time": 12,
    "start_from": new Date("2020-01-25T00:00:00.441+00:00"),
    "history": {
      "created_at": new Date("2020-01-23T00:00:00.441+00:00"),
      "accepted_at": new Date("2020-01-23T01:00:00.441+00:00")
    }
  },
  {
    "time": 24,
    "start_from": new Date("2020-01-25T06:00:00.441+00:00"),
    "history": {
      "created_at": new Date("2020-01-23T00:00:00.441+00:00"),
      "accepted_at": new Date("2020-01-23T00:30:00.441+00:00"),
      "completed_at": new Date("2020-01-25T07:00:00.441+00:00")
    }
  },
  {
    "time": 24,
    "start_from": new Date("2020-01-11T00:00:00.441+00:00"),
    "history": {
      "created_at": new Date("2020-01-09T00:00:00.441+00:00"),
      "accepted_at": new Date("2020-01-10T00:00:00.441+00:00")
    }
  }
]
```

**Query**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "deadline": {
        $add: [
          "$start_from",
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$time",
              3600000
            ]
          }
        ]
      },

    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "history.accepted_at": {
        $exists: true
      },
      "history.completed_at": null,
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          "$deadline",
          ISODate("2020-01-23T00:00:00.441Z")
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "end_deadline": ISODate("2020-01-25T12:00:00.441Z"),
    "history": {
      "accepted_at": ISODate("2020-01-23T01:00:00.441Z"),
      "created_at": ISODate("2020-01-23T00:00:00.441Z")
    },
    "start_from": ISODate("2020-01-25T00:00:00.441Z"),
    "time": 12
  }
]
```

You can see the working code in [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OEAD8lJikzt).

**NOTE**

- Difference between BSON date type and BSON timestamps

  > The BSON timestamp type is for internal MongoDB use. For most cases, in application development, you will want to use the BSON date type.
- BSON timestamp type and BSON Date type are both 64-bit integers.

*BSON Date type:*

> Internally, Date objects are stored as a signed 64-bit integer representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970).

*BSON Timestamps:*

> BSON has a special timestamp type for internal MongoDB use and is not associated with the regular Date type. This internal timestamp type is a 64 bit value where:
>
> - the most significant 32 bits are a time_t value (seconds since the Unix epoch)
> - the least significant 32 bits are an incrementing ordinal for operations within a given second.

[MongoDB official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps)

- You cannot use Date() function directly in query.

  > Date() returns the current date as a string in the mongo shell.

[It only works in mongo shell.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/) But in Node.js, it's OK because the mongo driver will convert it.

- ISODate is just a helper function.

  > ISODate() is a helper function that's built into to MongoDB and wraps the native JavaScript Date object. When you use the ISODate() constructor from the Mongo shell, it actually returns a JavaScript Date object.

[Compose Tips: Dates and Dating in MongoDB](https://www.compose.com/articles/understanding-dates-in-compose-mongodb/)