# How to put createdAt (timestamp ) manually in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

how can I add manually createdAt (timestamp ) field in MongoDB?

```
db.getCollection("properties").find({})
```

This returns all properties and this is an example:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6b3269617d327b82a71723"), 
    "title" : "Nice and cozy apartment", 
    "category" : "rent", 
    "town" : "London", 
    "price" : NumberInt(3100), 
    "square" : NumberInt(249), 
}
```

What I want to achieve is a field with timestamp or information about the date when a particular property is created.
Can anybody help with this?s?

Comment: See my answer here. You can get an idea of BSON date type in mongodb: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822405/mongodb-query-and-aggregation-for-bson-date-type/59874977#answer-59874977

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put a key in mongoose schema

```
createdAt:{type: Date, default: Date.now()}; 
//will add automatically putt entry in db whenever document created.
```

and use aggregate instead of find(becoz you don't have key createdAt in old document) as ,

```
db.orders.aggregate([
                     {
                        $addFields: {
                          "createdAt": { $ifNull: ["$createdAt", Date(manually whenever created)] },
                        }
                    }
                   ])
```